# Flutter Web persistent header

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

With the introduction of flutter for web it has me trying to achieve a website style header that is persistent when using routes and across the entire app. Appbar doesn't appear to be the solution since each scaffold has its own appBar. I've created the header widget that's in a `Column` with the `MaterialApp`. However, this implementation feels wrong as everything should be a child of MaterialApp or CupertinoApp.

If the searchBar header can be placed within the MaterialApp and I'm able to use Navigator that's would be preferred. I'm really here for guidance and the "right" way to do this.

```dart
void main() {
  initKiwi();
//  BlocSupervisor().delegate = AppBlocDelegate();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(children: <Widget>[
      Material(
        elevation: 2.0,
        color: Colors.white,
        child: MediaQuery(
          data: MediaQueryData.fromWindow(ui.window),
          child: Directionality(
            textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
            child: Container(
              height: 50,
              child: SearchBar(),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Expanded(
        child: MaterialApp(
          title: 'Discover Brindle',
          theme: ThemeData(
            primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
            fontFamily: 'Brdl',
          ),
          home: Text("Pages & Routes Here"),
        ),
      ),
    ]);
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though it's not using routes I was able to solve this using `IndexedStack`. This also preserves any scrolling I've done in the `ProductsPage()` when closing the search page. The AppBar is persistent and was able to keep the code to a minimum.

main.dart

```dart
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Discover Brindle',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        fontFamily: 'Brdl'
      ),
      home: MainPage(),
    );
  }
}
```

main_page.dart

```dart
class MainPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MainPageState createState() => _MainPageState();
}

class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {
  final _searchBloc = kiwi.Container().resolve<SearchBloc>();
  final _productsBloc = kiwi.Container().resolve<ProductsBloc>();
  PageController pageController;
  int currentPage = 0;

  void _onSearchActive({bool isActive}) {
    setState(() {
      this.currentPage = isActive ? 1 : 0;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(new FocusNode());
      },
      child: _buildScaffold(),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildScaffold() {
    return BlocProviderTree(
      blocProviders: [
        BlocProvider<SearchBloc>(bloc: _searchBloc),
        BlocProvider<ProductsBloc>(bloc: _productsBloc),
      ],
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          title: SearchBar(onIsActive: _onSearchActive),
        ),
        body: IndexedStack(
          children: [
            ProductsPage(),
            SearchPage(),
          ],
          index: currentPage,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```